# How to transition between multiple inline UINavigationControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm currently working on an app which transitions as follows:

Table view controller (embedded in a navigation controller) -->
Tab bar view controller -->
1 of 4 view controllers (each embedded in their own navigation controller)

After transitioning to 1 of the 4 embedded view controllers, I want the "new" navigation controller to take over, while still maintaining the stack of prior transitions (so that the user can easily go back). Unfortunately, the way things are, the original navigation seems to cover the newly generated navigation (whose title can faintly be seen behind the bar at the top).

I'd like to avoid programmatic approaches, where possible, as I prefer "storyboarding."

BTW: I'm developing using Swift in Xcode 6.2

Thanks.

Comment: I think you need to rethink your structure.  If I open the tab bar from the first nav controller, then switch to tab two, where does the back button go?

If you want to keep the stack, you'll need to base everything off the first nav controller.

Comment: I'd like for the back button of the 4 view controllers to return to the tab bar controller. The reason I have 4 view controllers embedded in their own navigation controllers is to allow for individual operation of edit/done buttons and their associated behaviors. If you have any suggestions, or helpful tips, as to a structure which would accomplish this, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @matt Thanks for your insight. I'm so glad you were able to constructively address the question at hand, which I'm sure you're more than qualified to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code and project, learn Swift 3, and learn programmatic changes. If you have any desire to be a quality iOS Developer, then learning to accept change is a huge step towards your own success. Adding a Navigation Controller in code is ridiculously easy. Forcing everything to be done through the storyboard only constricts yourself. I used this tutorial to help me get started with learning how to handle the stuff in code. https://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift

Use this to instansiate the NavigationController making sure that you have the same restoration identifier for the navigation controller here as you do in the storyboard, and that where I say "Main" it has the name of the storyboard where the navigation controller exists.

```
private extension UIStoryboard {
    class func mainStoryboard() -> UIStoryboard {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    }
    class func someNavigationController() -> UINavigationController? {
        return mainStoryboard().instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SomeNavigationController") as? UINavigationController
    }
}
```

as a class variable make:

```
var someNavigationController: UINavigationController!
var someViewController: UIViewController!
```

inside the function where you want to display the navigation controller so this:

```
someNavigationController = UIStoryboard.someNavigationController()!
someViewController = someNavigationController.childViewControllers.first! as! EiValueTableViewController
someNavigationController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
view.addSubview(someNavigationController.view)
addChildViewController(someNavigationController)
someNavigationController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

I have many view controllers that I do this sort of thing with. They are completely made in the storyboard still, but this allows you to use them any way you want instead of being forced to only transition with segues. If you still refuse to do things programmatically, then you can transition to a SplitViewController which it should be simple to find guides for, but I find them to be far to constricting for this kind of use.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but your response doesn't exactly address my question. I'm having trouble properly displaying the second set of navigation controllers, as the first navigation controller seems to be covering it. I'm also concerned that if I were to simply hide the original nav controller, even temporarily, that I would lose the auto generation of a dynamic back button to return to the tab bar controller.

Comment: You said you want to save it's state. If you do, then you myeswell cover it up unless you plan on storing things in a singleton or coreData and bringing them back to life which is far more complex. The method I show you is covering it up, but all you have to do at this point is something like 'UIView.animateWithDuration(1) { someNavigationController.view.origin.x = 0 - someNavigationController.view.frame.width }' then someNavigationController.view.removeFromSuperview then someNavigationController.removeFromParentController() then someNavigationController = nil and u are back to the start

Comment: Look at that tutorial and experiment with its code. It will teach you a lot!

Comment: I do plan on storing data via a singleton or core data, which is to be updated/restored in a previously visited controller. However, with all that aside, I'm still interested in achieving my goal with minimal code. I don't mind programming, but I'd rather modify the state of a pre-existing item, than create and initialize one from scratch (where possible).

Comment: Whether you write the code or tell the storyboard to do something, the same actions are happening in the background. If you are new to it, you might not handle garbage collection as well, but that doesn't really matter unless you make the same mistake 50 times in your code with that. I was in a similar position to you 6 months back at my job and finally concluded this was best. I virtually had no segues in my project for a while, and eventually come back around so they are 50-50 segues or not. When you mess with multiple Navigation Controllers or sharing the screen,...

Comment: there is only so much control that you will have unless you do it programmatically. To answer your question further now that I reread it, You might be able to present it modally and a form sheet or something. Is this Strictly iPhone or iPad?

Comment: For now it's strictly for iPhone (any dimension) in portrait mode only. I basically want a universal back button which displays the name of the tab bar controller which precedes the 4 view controllers.

Comment: Just because it is Universal, doesn't mean two views can't contain it in the same spot. In order to give you an exact answer, I would almost need a video of you using the App explaining what you wanted though. Just know that without code, I can't guarantee it is even possible, and with code I can guarantee it is.

Comment: Firstly, I never said that two views can't contain the same button in the same spot. Second, while I appreciate the offer, I think I'll have to respectfully decline. I'll probably due some further research. Third, I'd like to address a point that was made earlier by yourself. One shouldn't assume the goals, resources, and motivation of another. My reasons for not using Xcode 3 and the newest version of Swift are personal, and not due to an aversion towards newer software or change in general. While an inclination towards interface builder is noted as having limitations, it is my preference.

Comment: Maybe so, but developers that actually knwo what they are talking about nearly always use the latest most up to date software. Sometimes they take it a step further and are using beta software. This being said, if you want to know something more than a version or two older than the current release that is actually specific to that version, you really are wasting your time here. P.S. If you really want to use the storyboard that bad, than updating to Swift 3 is HUGE!

Comment: The storyboard functionality is greatly improved since just the previous version let alone what you are using. I dare say it is what differs the most since the version you are on and you are asking storyboard specific questions.